# Subir imagen desde Windows Forms a PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una aplicacion de windows forms con un openfiledialog y cargo una imagen en un picturebox. Para subirla a un servidor donde hay una api de PHP:

```
public string Guardar_pr(E_Propiedades Epr)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://cms.inmobiliarianormaperez.com/cmsi");
        var request = new RestRequest("/propiedad", Method.Post);
        request.AddParameter("id", Epr.id);
        request.AddParameter("nombre", Epr.nombre);
        request.AddParameter("dc", Epr.dc);
        request.AddParameter("dl", Epr.dl);
        request.AddParameter("situacion", Epr.situacion);
        request.AddParameter("condicion", Epr.condicion);
        request.AddParameter("archivo", Epr.img_principal);
        request.AddParameter("ubicacion", Epr.ubicacion);
        request.AddParameter("ciudad", Epr.ciudad);
        request.AddParameter("barrio", Epr.barrio);
        request.AddParameter("tipo_propiedad", Epr.tipo_propiedad);
        request.AddParameter("banos", Epr.banos);
        request.AddParameter("dormitorios", Epr.dormitorios);
        request.AddParameter("dueño", Epr.dueño);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ToString());
        if (response.Content == "OK")
        {
            return "OK";
        }
        else
        {
            return "eRROR2";
        }
    }
```

El parametro "archivo" guarda la url que se obtiene del OpenFileDialog.

Luego tengo en el metodo de addPropiedades de mi controlador:

```
 public function subirImagenlocal($imagen){
 $total_imagenes = count(glob('../cmsi/App/img/{*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png}',GLOB_BRACE)) +1;

        $uploadedFile = '';
  
            $valid_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $temporary = explode(".", $imagen);
            $file_extension = end($temporary);
            $fileName = "imagen".$total_imagenes.".".$file_extension;

                $sourcePath = $imagen;
        
                $targetPath = "../cmsi/App/img/".$fileName;
                
                    if(move_uploaded_file($imagen,$targetPath)){
                      echo "subido";
                    }else{
                        echo "error";
                    }
   
        return $fileName;

}
```

Me obtiene el nombre de archivo y lo guarda en la base de datos perfectamente..pero no sube el fichero al servidor.
Es decir falla la funcion move_uploaded_file

Comment: php por defecto carga la imagen a un lugar y nombre temporal y este es el que debes usar para mover el archivo https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]; si usas un framework revisa bien la forma y la sintaxis.

Comment: ¿No deberías usar `request.AddFile()`?.